# How to remove black background after rotation function applied in php GD?

Tags: php, gd

In my case, I have created a php script for merging many images into single image. During the merge process, I want rotate few images.

The script is working fine. But the rotated images are shows black background color.

I should remove the black background color.

I am using the below script for handle rotate features in php. 
This script can merge three png images with rotate features.

Issues:

- some dark lines shows around the image when after the rotation in IE 8 .
- Background shows black color instead of white

How to solve these issues.

Please fix this script issues and post your answers.

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 600);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 000, 000, 000);


$source=imagecreatefrompng("http://cn1.kaboodle.com/img/c/0/0/179/4/AAAADDpe-ZwAAAAAAXlIhA/funny-shirt-pikachu-pokemon-anime-mens-cool-humor-t-shirt.png?v=1313557837000");
$asd=imagerotate($source, 280, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd, $white);
imageantialias($asd, true);
$insert_x = imagesx($asd); 
$insert_y = imagesy($asd);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x , $insert_y , 100 );


$source1=imagecreatefrompng("http://www.vouchersmate.com/content/images/thumbs/0001595_worlds_best_dad_to_be_t_shirts.png");
$asd1=imagerotate($source1, 180, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd1, $white);
imageantialias($asd1, true);
$insert_x1 = imagesx($asd1); 
$insert_y1 = imagesy($asd1);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd1 , 110 , 55 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x1 , $insert_y1 , 100 );


$source2=imagecreatefrompng("http://goalwa.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/green_shirt.png?w=300&h=300");
$asd2=imagerotate($source2, 320, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd2, $white);
imageantialias($asd2, true);
$insert_x2 = imagesx($asd2); 
$insert_y2 = imagesy($asd2);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd2 , 170 , 90 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x2 , $insert_y2 , 100 );



imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

imageantialias($im, true);

imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

---

I am using the below script for handle rotate features in php. 
This script can merge three png images with rotate features.

Issues:

- some dark lines shows around the image when after the rotation in IE 8 .
- Background shows black color instead of white

How to solve these issues.

Please fix this script issues and post your answers.

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 600);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 000, 000, 000);


$source=imagecreatefrompng("http://cn1.kaboodle.com/img/c/0/0/179/4/AAAADDpe-ZwAAAAAAXlIhA/funny-shirt-pikachu-pokemon-anime-mens-cool-humor-t-shirt.png?v=1313557837000");
$asd=imagerotate($source, 280, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd, $white);
imageantialias($asd, true);
$insert_x = imagesx($asd); 
$insert_y = imagesy($asd);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x , $insert_y , 100 );


$source1=imagecreatefrompng("http://www.vouchersmate.com/content/images/thumbs/0001595_worlds_best_dad_to_be_t_shirts.png");
$asd1=imagerotate($source1, 180, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd1, $white);
imageantialias($asd1, true);
$insert_x1 = imagesx($asd1); 
$insert_y1 = imagesy($asd1);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd1 , 110 , 55 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x1 , $insert_y1 , 100 );


$source2=imagecreatefrompng("http://goalwa.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/green_shirt.png?w=300&h=300");
$asd2=imagerotate($source2, 320, 0);
imagecolortransparent($asd2, $white);
imageantialias($asd2, true);
$insert_x2 = imagesx($asd2); 
$insert_y2 = imagesy($asd2);
imagecopymerge ( $im , $asd2 , 170 , 90 , 0 , 0 , $insert_x2 , $insert_y2 , 100 );



imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

imageantialias($im, true);

imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
```

Comment: Hello, you can add some code for us to help you pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to examine, it is hard to pinpoint your problem exactly, but I'll try:

The black you are seeing is the absence of color. What you probably want is for that area to be transparent instead. Try adding the following code:

```
imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for the background to actually be?

You can use [imagefilledrectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) to fill the background in any colour you'd prefer. For example, let's say you have an image which is width 500px and height 250px;

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 500, 250, $white);
```

You've now got a full white background to work with. You can also look at imagecolortransparent; http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php if you want to create a transparent background.